# Is it possible to prevent CGDB from clearing screen on exit?

Tags: c++, debugging, cgdb

When I run CGDB I see all of the code/backtraces/stdout stuff just fine. When I exit, it all gets cleared (just like when I exit vim, for instance). As a result I lose all the output.

I realize it would be a bit strange since it sort has a pager built in already. I just haven't found any reference in the `info cgdb` docs that suggests there's any magic to keep logs around.

Comment: The whole point of *c*gdb is that it's the *C*urses UI for gdb. This behavior is typical for curses apps.

Answer (score 2):

The GDB commands `set logging on`, `set logging file` and `set logging off` may be of use to you.

Comment: Interesting. There's some good info in the log that generates, but it doesn't have any stdout/err type output.